# How to use react-select types when creating custom components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am trying to create custom components for DropdownIndicator and use on react-select with Typescript, but I am having some issues with the type of the component because I am new to typescript.

How can I use types defined on @types/react-select on my component?

I've installed @types/react-select and there is already a [type for DropdownIndicator](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/518700405e6f24d00288c4bb3bf56d2d4b8dae97/types/react-select/src/components/indicators.d.ts#L31), but I've found no way to reference it.

This is my `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

import DropdownIndicator from './dropdown-indicator';

const components = {
  DropdownIndicator,
};

const SelectFilter: React.FC = () => {
  return <Select components={components} />;
};

export default React.memo(SelectFilter);
```

This is my `dropdown-indicator.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

import DropdownIcon from './dropdown-icon';

const DropdownIndicator: React.FC = props => {
  const {
    selectProps: { isMenuOpen },
  } = props;

  return <DropdownIcon isUp={isMenuOpen} />;
};

export default React.memo(DropdownIndicator);
```

Since I didn't defined any prop types, the error is:

```
/Users/felipepinheiro/Workspace/test/src/components/select-filter/dropdown-indicator.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/felipepinheiro/Workspace/test/src/components/select-filter/dropdown-indicator.tsx(7,5):
Property 'selectProps' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2339

     5 | const DropdownIndicator: React.FC = props => {
     6 |   const {
  >  7 |     selectProps: { isMenuOpen },
       |     ^
     8 |   } = props;
     9 | 
    10 |   return <DropdownIcon isUp={isMenuOpen} />;
```

Comment: use `props.selectProps.menuIsOpen` not `isMenuOpen` ;) and do not destruct them.

Comment: You could do something like this where you pass the component directly into the function and import the IndicatorProps type 

```ts
import {IndicatorProps } from 'react-select';


const SelectFilter: React.FC = () => {
  return <Select components={{
    Indicator: (indicatorProps: IndicatorProps<any>) => (
      <components.DropdownIndicator {...indicatorProps} />
    ),
  }} />;
};
```

Answer (score 8):

I left a comment but putting this in an answer since  it'll be more legible with proper formatting

You can directly import the IndicatorProps type from react-select package and then pass your props to the component directly from within your select component

```
import { IndicatorProps, OptionType } from 'react-select';


const SelectFilter: React.FC = () => {
  return <Select components={{
    Indicator: (indicatorProps: IndicatorProps<OptionType>) => (
      <components.DropdownIndicator {...indicatorProps} />
    ),
  }} />;
};
```

Comment: What is the right way to avoid `any` inside `Record<string, unknown>`?

Comment: I think if you import the `OptionType` type and use that instead of `<any>` it should work correctly

Comment: It works. But there is a problem with [@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) ESLint rule, and I'm asking to figure out how to overcome it correctly.

Comment: I'm familiar with the rule, so I updated my above example to include my proposed answer that uses `<OptionType>` instead of `<any>`. Where are you trying to use `Record<string, unknown>`? If you show me an example I might be able to better help

Comment: It looks like I missed it. Thanks!